# How can I find the origin of equation about this filter circuit?

Tags: filter, ota

Probably everything is clear for anyone but I can't still understand how can the author found the Vo equation for this circuit. I hope somebody in here will show me the way.

[image: circuit]

[image]

Comment: I don't even recognize the symbols you use. Can you explain them first? CCII is related to a dual-output second-generation current conveyors (DO-CCII)?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot explain , but these transfer functions are derived from standard VI nodal matrix calculations.

I hope this may help you.  http://nopr.niscair.res.in/bitstream/123456789/11677/1/IJEMS%2018(2)%2097-101.pdf

Below  in 1996 the DDCC "Differential Difference Current mode Conveyor" is then combined to next filter. It has 4 inputs x,y1,y2,y3 and  differential outputs z1,z2 .  This symbol can be simplified to show differential +- inputs y2,y3 and x,y1.  These devices depend on perfectly matched components.

[image]

e.g. [image]